# CodeIgniter Route Problem with Regex

Tags: php, url, codeigniter, routes

I have got a little problem using the CodeIgniter route function.

I use the [URI_Language_Identifier extension](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/URI_Language_Identifier) and I want to reroute all 
the requests for "lang/login" (e.g. en/login or de/login) to user/login I tried to use the routes function as follows, but it does not work:

`$route['(\w{2})/login'] = "/user/index";`

this however does work:

`$route['en/login'] = "/user/index";

$route['de/login'] = "/user/index";`

but the working version is pretty bad, it will produce redundant code and you have to change to much if you want to add a new language.

I hope someone has an intelligent answer, as usual. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or try $route[':any/login'] = "/user/index";

Comment: This seems to work now. I do not know why, but regular expressions do not work at all. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**The real error & solution**

Hey,
just if someone has the same problem, I found the real error.

The is a line in the route.php

`//route example: http://domain.tld/en/controller => http://domain.tld/controller

$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';

$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];`

This is from the extension.

You need to put all your routes before this, like in the following:

`$route['(\w{2})/signup'] = "user/signup";

//route example: http://domain.tld/en/controller => http://domain.tld/controller

$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';

$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];`

Thanks for all the help in this post anyway. You are great.

Answer (score 1):

Any Routes using RegEx **must** be placed after the reserved routes of `scaffolding_trigger` and `default_controller` this is most likely your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$route['.+/login'] = "/user/index";
```

since you don't need the matched language code anyway.
I guess something's wrong with the interpretation of your `(\w{2})` expression, maybe you'd also have to try something like:

```
$route['[a-z]+/login'] = "/user/index";
```

Answer (score 0):

All the 3 do not work for me.

Just providing some more information: I am running it on a local server.

Also I have an .htaccess file with the following code:

`AddCharset utf-8 .css .html .xhtml

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/veare/index.php/$1 [L]`

I get a 404 error.

Hope you have some more ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that handles the REGEX part of the routing:

// Loop through the route array looking for wild-cards

```
    foreach ($this->routes as $key => $val)
    {                       
        // Convert wild-cards to RegEx
        $key = str_replace(':any', '.+', str_replace(':num', '[0-9]+', $key));

        // Does the RegEx match?
        if (preg_match('#^'.$key.'$#', $uri))
        {           
            // Do we have a back-reference?
            if (strpos($val, '$') !== FALSE AND strpos($key, '(') !== FALSE)
            {
                $val = preg_replace('#^'.$key.'$#', $val, $uri);
            }

            $this->_set_request(explode('/', $val));        
            return;
        }
    }
```

I would try

```
$route['\w\w/login'] = "/user/index";
```

Comment: It seems to not work as well. Would you need me to provide any more information? Please let me know how I could make it easier to help me, if there is any help.

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is, that CI does not like me using regex and a normal name. So I would need to tell "login" in regex as well. Sadly I am totally stupid when it comes to regex, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (Provided the language is always lowercase):

```
$route['([a-z]{2})/login'] = '/user/index';
```

As Watain mentioned, since you don't need the matched lang. code, you can drop the '(' and ')'

```
$route['[a-z]{2}/login'] = '/user/index';
```